# How can I change the backlight of an external monitor?

Tags: x11, backlight

I have a laptop with an external monitor connected via HDMI (output name is `HDMI1`). The command `xbacklight` works only with my primary screen (which is the laptop screen).

It doesn't work even if I try running it with argument `-display HDMI1` (which gives me an error `RANDR Query Version returned error -1`) or `--display HDMI1` (which gives me the help information).

I have seen this - [Turn off the backlight of an external monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219001/turn-off-the-backlight-of-an-external-monitor) - question but it only mentions how to change the **brightness**, not **backlight**.

EDIT: the option `-display` is not documented in the manual page of `xbacklight`, but after a quick look into the source code I've found [where it's used](https://github.com/tcatm/xbacklight/blob/7db4876cdeaa5d25cb857bead7153ef503e993d6/xbacklight.c#L218). In the function `xcb_connect` it [represents the X display, not the actual screen name](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/group__XCB__Core__API.html#ga094470586356d1764e69c9a1882966c3).

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with `ddcutil`, as mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#External_monitors), but it's not that responsive and requires root privileges:

```
# ddcutil capabilities | grep Brightness
  Feature: 10 (Brightness)

# ddcutil getvcp 10
VCP code 0x10 (Brightness                    ): current value =    60, max value =   100

# ddcutil setvcp 10 70
```

I don't think that there's "one size fits all" solution since the backlight configuration depends on the hardware. In some situations, you cannot control the backlight even of the built-in laptop monitor.

Comment: All I'm getting is `Display not found`, even after adding `-d` flag. ):

Comment: As mentioned in @prosoitos response, you need to load i2c-dev module e.g. `modprobe i2c-dev` as root

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [ddcutil](http://www.ddcutil.com/) (for instance if your monitor does not support DDC/CI, or you don't want to load an extra kernel module (`i2c-dev`), or you don't have permission to access `/dev/i2c-*`), is to use [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/).

redshift controls the color temperature, but it also controls the screen brightness.

You can set a config file to have different brightness (and different color temperatures too if you wish) during the day and at night, or you can change either of these on the fly from the command line.

From the command line, in a multi-monitor situation, you need to use the `-m` flag. Your primary monitor is `crtc=0` and your external `crtc=1`. You can also use the name of your monitor given by `xrandr`.

So, for instance, to set a brightness of 70% on your external monitor, you can run:

```bsh
redshidft -m randr:crtc=1 -b 0.7 &
```

If you are using a config file, add to it:

```bsh
[randr]
screen=0
crtc=1
```

(It would be `crtc=0` for the config file of your primary monitor. [This issue](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/23) covers this.)

If you are already using redshift on your primary screen, you can have 2 running instances of redshift with different settings for each of your monitor. You can even have 2 different config files (load the 2nd redshift instance with the `-c` flag to give it the path to your 2nd config file).

One thing to be aware of is that, even after you have killed a redshift instance, the settings remain active. To go back to your normal settings, you need to run `redshift -x` (so, again, for your external monitor, this would be `redshift -m randr:crtc=1 -x`). If you kill an instance, then launch another one without first running this command, the settings will be cumulative. This is bit of a weird behaviour, but it actually has some advantages: in some cases, depending on how they are launched, 2 concomitant instances can create some flickering. If this were ever to happen, you can simply kill one (or both) to stop the problem: the settings will remain.

All this may seem very complicated, but once you are familiar with it and you have set some  config files, or aliases, or keybindings, it actually works very well. And if you launch your redshift instances from `.xinitrc` for instance, you may never have to fiddle with it anymore as the brightness will automatically adjust at dusk and down.

---

**edit:**
My comment about redshift not resetting the default monitor values upon being killed above was a mistake on my part:

- if gently asked to die and cleanup with signal 15 (e.g. `kill -15 <pid>`, which is the default signal value for `kill`), it will actually reset things as part of the cleanup
- if killed with signal 9 (e.g. `kill -9 <pid>`), it will stop without resetting anything

This makes sense, but I had never realized it. In the situations in which multiple instances of redshift create some flickering, I take advantage of this and launch, then immediately kill (with some function) a new instance. It is probably not very clean... but it has worked for me very well so far.

Comment: Redshift doesn't actually change the monitor brightness (illumination), for the reasons of the existence of this question (there's no standard way). Instead it tries to mimic that by adjusting the gamma on the output color settings via randr (i.e. it makes colors more washed/shady).

Comment: In the redshift conf file there is a gamma value **and** a brightness value though. **Edit:** You are right. I had never realized that. I just read on it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -2):

xbacklight may be your answer:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#xbacklight

Brightness and Backlight seems to be the same thing. If so, go for `xrandr` since every output are supported.

Comment: These two are **NOT** the same thing. Brightness in `xrandr` represents pixels "whiteness", backlight in `xbacklight` represents the LED backlight. I took a picture of both of my screens - https://i.imgur.com/oSXfCGr.jpg The left screen has brightness set to 0 with `xrandr`, the right one has backlight set to 0 with `xbacklight`. Notice the "glare" - these are pixels displaying black color and being shined on. (;

Comment: See also the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlight